# Springboot + JPA : List all fieldnames for each fieldtype

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot + JPA for my project. I want a `fieldName` list for each `type` from my table. So I did this by using **query with named parameters** using `JPQL`. I made two methods in the repository.

1. **First Method:**
                                    This method is for getting distinct list of `type`.

```java
      @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT fc.type FROM FieldCapabilityModel fc")
      List<String> findDistinctType();
```

2. **Second Method:**
                                                   This method is for getting a list of names for particular `type`.

```java
     @Query("SELECT fc.fieldName FROM FieldCapabilityModel fc where fc.type=:type")
     List<String> findByType(@Param("type) String type);
```

This is my `service` component.

```java
@Service
public class FieldCapabilityService {

    @Autowired
    FieldCapabilityRepo fcRepo;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> getAllFieldAndType() { 
                // First Method is called here  
        return fcRepo.findDistinctType().stream().map(type -> {
                Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                resultMap.put("type", type);
                // Second Method is called here
                resultMap.put("field", fcRepo.findByType(type));
                return resultMap;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());            
    }
}
```

When I called using the rest controller my API response is:

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Data Fetched",
  "data": [
    {
      "field": [
        "name.lname",
        "city",
        "name.fname",
        "name",
        "id"
      ],
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "field": [
        "_ignored"
      ],
      "type": "_ignored"
    },
    {
      "field": [
        "_seq_no"
      ],
      "type": "_seq_no"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting the exact output as I want and also this is a simple data response I have more than 16 types. Albeit I want to know that this is an efficient and robust way.
My questions are:

> **Can we use any other queries for this?**
>   **Can we use `@NamedQuery` instead of this if yes then why?**
>   **What should be the reduced, robust, and efficient method for this execution?**

Please give me suggestions if I want to improve anything into this solution or propose a new solution if that is better than this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch all type & fieldName in one query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair(fc.type as type, fc.fieldName as name) FROM FieldCapabilityModel fc")
  public List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> findAllTypeWithName();
```

And then summarize data. Create a map of Type where Key is fieldNames

```
Map<String, List<String>> fieldNameByType = fcRepo.findAllTypeWithName()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getKey, 
                Collectors.mapping(Pair::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Then you can prepare your response using this map.

```
return fieldNameByType.entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
                Map<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                resultMap.put("type", e.getKey());
                resultMap.put("field", e.getValue());
                return resultMap;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Where to define key and values? can you please suggest me also how to define key value for this like `Pair <String, List<String>> pair=  
                         new Pair <> ("", new ArryList<String>());`

Comment: I summarize data as you said but it gives an error that `Pair` doesn't define `getKey` and `getValue`.

Comment: Use `org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair` may be you are using different doc here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Pair.html

Comment: Ohk I will check and test once again and inform you otherwise this is a good approach.

Comment: It's working @Eklavya. I test this solution and it is exactly as I want. Thanks for the solution.