# Mapping mysql query to entity

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class which I am using to save readings to database.

```
@Entity(name = "readings")
data class ReadingEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) val id: Long = 0,
        val name: String,
        @get: NotBlank val serialNumber: String,
        val volume: Float,
        val consumption: Float,
        val date: Date,
        val state: State,
        val intervals: Int = 0,
        val infoCode: Int
)
```

I can easily retrieve these readings but I would like to get something like this.

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT *, sum(consumption) as consumption FROM readings " +
                "WHERE serial_number=:serial_number AND date>:date_limit  GROUP BY MONTH(date)",
        nativeQuery = true
)
fun getMonthlyConsumption(
        @Param("serial_number") serial_number: String,
        @Param("date_limit") dateLimit: Date
): List<ReadingEntity>
```

The value I am getting for consumption is not correct. Actually what I am interesting in is, to get the date and sum of consumption.

Comment: Only date and sum of consumption ?

Comment: Yes because when I groupBy month, week or whatever, I need to know what date this consumption belongs to.

Comment: Sum of consumption based on what? The month of the date? Pls provide sample data and expected results!

Comment: Use [Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) of  for map value and use JPQL, here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61919434/4207306)